# Find maximum value of a function over a given region

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

The prompt is to find the maximum value of the function 
$f(x) = 10 - 5x^2 -9y^2$ over the region $4x^2+y^2 \leq 4$.

This is what I tried doing, The method of Lagrange multipliers says that extrema of $f(x, y)$ subject to the constraint are found among the solutions of $\nabla(x, y) = \lambda\nabla g(x, y)$, where

This will only give us 2 values of $\lambda$ ,$\frac{5}{4}$ and $-9$ but x and y are still 0

I'm lost now what to do with $\lambda$ since my points are (0, 0) how to proceed with this problem?

Comment: Your expression for $f$ has no $y$, perhaps you mistyped something.

Comment: It doesn't, at least that's what the question says

Comment: Then what's the point of writing it as $10-5x^2-9x^2$ as opposed to $10-14x^2$.

Comment: In which case, $x=0$ will trivially give you the maximum value because $10-14x^2 \leq 10$. No need for Lagrange method.